# Espresso: How to test the style of a WebView element's contents

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am wondering if there is a way to assert on the style of a WebView element's contents in Espresso. I am aware of the ability to get the text of an element, however, I would like to do more testing. I haven't been able to find clear documentation on how to do things like getting the background-color or text-color of a button or the text-size using the onWebView.withElement logic. Is this even possible?

Consider this example:

```
Web.onWebView(withId(R.id.my_btn_id))
    .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID,"_the_id_of_a_button"))
    .check(webMatches({how to reference button text color}, "#0102333"));

Web.onWebView(withId(R.id.my_btn_id))
    .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID,"_the_id_of_a_button"))
    .check(webMatches({how to reference background color}, "#0302223"));

Web.onWebView(withId(R.id.my_btn_id))
    .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID,"_the_id_of_a_button"))
    .check(webMatches({how to reference text size}, "12px"));
```

Even getting the style value would help.

Note, I am aware of how to obtain these via evaluateJavascript. This is purely an Espresso question.

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea Espresso handled web stuff directly - sorry for the useless earlier comment! It doesn't look like there's anything out of the box that lets you query style attributes, but maybe you could subclass `SimpleAtom` (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/web/model/SimpleAtom) with a script that does the checks you need? Those basically run JS on an `ElementReference` you've looked up, and you can pass in arguments and return a result

Comment: There's also some implementations where you can just pass in a script parameter if you like, e.g. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/web/model/Atoms#scriptWithArgs(java.lang.String,%20java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.Object%3E) . Passing whichever atom to the `transform` function in there (or using a `TransformingAtom`) might be helpful - it's what they do in their `getCurrentUrl` atom to make it return a `String` https://github.com/android/android-test/blob/6e20b32b1176aaf8057fa847a0ef2a3ca17de5c8/espresso/web/java/androidx/test/espresso/web/model/Atoms.java#L60